# A Memory Issue in simple C Program Concerning Char Pointers

Tags: c

## Issue

I have a memory issue that arises when I use a large text file (sourced from project Gutenberg: Alice In Wonderland), but doesn't happen in some smaller text files (a two line test text file and a Maya Angelou poem).

In the large text file I receive a segmentation fault and when using Valgrind it reports an "Invalid write of size 1" and an "Invalid read of size 1". Upon inspection it seems to be in a function I have written that gets each word from a passed in line. It seems to complain about a single address location being 0 bytes after a block of size 50 was alloc'd.

I have looked at my code where I malloc 50 characters to a char pointer, but am unsure what is going wrong in the large text file that is not going wrong in the smaller text files. Also what seems odd is when I run in my debug mode I wrote it goes to the end and reaches the EOF that I verify with feof(fp).

I am hoping someone can spot what is going on and what I have missed since I don't program in C very often. Thank you in advance for any help in understanding what is going on.

### Program Overview

I pulled out the parts of my program I am writing and put it into a simple main to make things clearer and hopefully make it easier to spot the issue. The program roughly breaks down to:

- pass in text file
- open text file pointer with "r+"
- loop line by line with fgets
- replace '\n' or '\r' with '\0' in each line
- loop through line and extract each word (tokenized by isspace()) until '\0' is reached
- hashes word
- free pointers used
- close file pointer

The Valgrind output shows the issue occurring in the getWord() function. I have looked at it and tried outputting it character by character and inspecting it, but I am not seeing why the segfault happens and only in the large text file.

### Code

**main.c**

```
/*
 * License: GPLv3
 *
 * File: main.c
 *
 * Description: A program.
 *
 * Author:  Brandon Authier (hblkr)
 * Date:    6 Aug 2017
 * Version: 1.0
 *
 */

// Includes for program to run
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Global debug
bool DEBUG = false;

/* A djb2 hash function sourced online.
 */
unsigned long hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}

/*
 * Using a file pointer, get the first word and then pass a copy of the word
 * back
 *
 * @returns: a boolean of true when word is built
 *
 * TODO: Find issue in here causing memory error
 *
 */
bool getWord(char* line, int* idx, char* word)
{
    int wordIdx = 0;

    // Build word character by character
    for ( ; line[*idx] != '\0'; *idx = (*idx + 1))
    {
        if (isalpha(line[*idx]) || (line[*idx] == '-'))
        {
            word[wordIdx++] = tolower(line[*idx]);
        }
        else if (isspace(line[*idx]))
        {
            *idx += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/*
 * Process file. Tokenize each line and process each word.
 *
 * TODO: Process file.
 */
void processFile(FILE* textFp)
{
    // Variables to hold:
    //   a line for text
    //   a word once it is parsed
    //   an index to keep track of the line
    char line[1024] = "";
    unsigned char* word = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 50);
    int* lineIdx = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int lineCount = 1;

    // Set the line index to keep track of the line
    *lineIdx = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), textFp) != NULL)
    {
        // Get line character Count
        int charcount = 0;
        int wordCount = 1;

        for(int m = 0; line[m] != '\0'; m++)
        {
            // By counting spaces, you can get a rough estimate of how many words
            // are in each line. (totalSpaces + 1)
            if ((line[m] == ' ') && (line[m - 1] != ' '))
            {
                 wordCount++;
            }

            if(line[m] != '\n' && line[m] != '\r')
            {
                charcount++;
            }
            else
            {
                line[m] = '\0';
            }
        }

        if (DEBUG == true)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "line %d:\n", lineCount);
            fprintf(stdout, "  words in line: %d\n", wordCount);
            fprintf(stdout, "  charcount: %d\n", charcount);
            fprintf(stdout, "  lineIdx: %d\n", *lineIdx);
            fprintf(stdout, "  value: \"%s\"\n\n", line);
        }

        // Get word
        while (*lineIdx < (charcount - 1))
        {
            // Sanitize word
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                word[i] = '\0';
            }

            getWord(line, lineIdx, word);
            unsigned long hash_output = hash(word);

            if (DEBUG == true)
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "key: %10d,\t", hash_output);
                fprintf(stdout, "value: %8s,\t", word);
                fprintf(stdout, "lineIdx: %2d\n", *lineIdx);
            }
        } // End while for word

        if (DEBUG == true) { fprintf(stdout, "\n========\n\n"); }

        // Reset line index to 0 for new line
        *lineIdx = 0;
        lineCount++;
    } // End while for line

    if (DEBUG == true) { if (feof(textFp)) { fprintf(stderr, "Reached FEOF.\n"); } }

    // Free pointers
    free(lineIdx);
    free(word);
}


// Main
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  //        VERIFY COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS NECESSARY FOR PROGRAM
  //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    // User did not pass in any argument
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: main afile.txt\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Grab text file, possibly turn on debug, and ignore other arguments
    if (argc >= 3)
    {
        // For debug purposes
        if (strcmp("-d", argv[2]) == 0)
        {
            DEBUG = true;
            fprintf(stdout, "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "+            [DEBUGGING ON]           +\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n");
        }
    }


  //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  //        PROCESS PASSED IN TEXT FILE
  //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    // Open file for reading
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

    // If fp is NULL, file does not exist
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File does not exist.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (DEBUG == true) { fprintf(stdout, "File exists.\n"); }
    if (DEBUG == true)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "================================================================================\n");
    }

    // Process file
    processFile(fp);

    // Close file pointer
    if (fclose(fp) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File did not close.\n");
    }
    if (DEBUG == true) { fprintf(stdout, "File closed.\n"); }
    if (DEBUG == true)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "================================================================================\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    }


  //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  //        FREE ALL MEMORY THAT HASN'T BEEN FREED YET
  //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


    exit(0);
}
```

The following function seems to be where the issue arises somehow.

**getWord()**

```
/*
 * Using a file pointer, get the first word and then pass a copy of the word
 * back
 *
 * @returns: a boolean of true when word is built
 *
 * TODO: Find issue in here causing memory error
 *
 */
bool getWord(char* line, int* idx, char* word)
{
    int wordIdx = 0;

    // Build word character by character
    for ( ; line[*idx] != '\0'; *idx = (*idx + 1))
    {
        if (isalpha(line[*idx]) || (line[*idx] == '-'))
        {
            word[wordIdx++] = tolower(line[*idx]);
        }
        else if (isspace(line[*idx]))
        {
            *idx += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Error Output

After compiling and then running here is the output I get when not running in debug mode (debug is really just verbose mode for myself):

**`./main alice.txt`**

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**`valgrind -q --leak-check=full ./main alice.txt`**

```
==7320== Invalid write of size 1
==7320==    at 0x400A24: getWord (in /tmp/main)
==7320==    by 0x400C7B: processFile (in /tmp/main)
==7320==    by 0x400F32: main (in /tmp/main)
==7320==  Address 0x51f62e2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 50 alloc'd
==7320==    at 0x4C28BF6: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==7320==    by 0x400AE5: processFile (in /tmp/main)
==7320==    by 0x400F32: main (in /tmp/main)
==7320== 
==7320== Invalid read of size 1
==7320==    at 0x400972: hash (in /tmp/main)
==7320==    by 0x400C87: processFile (in /tmp/main)
==7320==    by 0x400F32: main (in /tmp/main)
==7320==  Address 0x51f62e2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 50 alloc'd
==7320==    at 0x4C28BF6: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==7320==    by 0x400AE5: processFile (in /tmp/main)
==7320==    by 0x400F32: main (in /tmp/main)
==7320==
```

### Text Files

Here are the 3 I have tested the program with:

**test.txt**

```
This isn't only a test, it's a lot of fun!
How did I get-here?... Well, I'm not sure either.
```

**maya.txt**

```
Pretty women wonder where my secret lies.
I'm not cute or built to suit a fashion model's size
But when I start to tell them,
They think I'm telling lies.
I say,
It's in the reach of my arms
The span of my hips,
The stride of my step,
The curl of my lips.
I'm a woman
Phenomenally.
Phenomenal woman,
That's me.

I walk into a room
Just as cool as you please,
And to a man,
The fellows stand or
Fall down on their knees.
Then they swarm around me,
A hive of honey bees.
I say,
It's the fire in my eyes,
And the flash of my teeth,
The swing in my waist,
And the joy in my feet.
I'm a woman
Phenomenally.
Phenomenal woman,
That's me.

Men themselves have wondered
What they see in me.
They try so much
But they can't touch
My inner mystery.
When I try to show them
They say they still can't see.
I say,
It's in the arch of my back,
The sun of my smile,
The ride of my breasts,
The grace of my style.
I'm a woman

Phenomenally.
Phenomenal woman,
That's me.

Now you understand
Just why my head's not bowed.
I don't shout or jump about
Or have to talk real loud.
When you see me passing
It ought to make you proud.
I say,
It's in the click of my heels,
The bend of my hair,
the palm of my hand,
The need of my care,
'Cause I'm a woman
Phenomenally.
Phenomenal woman,
That's me.
```

**alice.txt**

Here is the [text](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/19033/pg19033.txt)

Comment: If you are `free`ing in the same function as you are `malloc`ing, why not just use arrays and normal integers?

Comment: `if ((line[m] == ' ') && (line[m - 1] != ' '))` : When the beginning of sentence is space(`m == 0`), access outside the range of array (`line[m - 1]`).

Comment: BTW Are you using `alice.txt` plain text?

Comment: The only problem I run into on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 with GCC 7.2.0 and Valgrind 3.13.0.SVN is at the line in the first `for` loop of `processFile()`: `if ((line[m] == ' ') && (line[m - 1] != ' '))` — sometimes in Alice `m` was `0`.  Changing that to `if ((line[m] == ' ') && (m == 0 || line[m - 1] != ' '))` fixes the warning about 'Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)'.

Comment: Hit by a wall of code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [mcve] means that you strip the program to bare essentials. Since you had debugging turned *off* when reproducing the problem, then you must strip out the debugging prints too - what would we do with them?!

Comment: Also, if you use a recent GCC, try `-fsanitize=undefined`

Comment: How is the code compiled and linked? The output of valgrind is easier to interpret if it has line numbers.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - How would I keep track of the line index while getting each word? I'm not opposed to using a different means of keeping track, but using a pointer seemed the best way.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ah, I think you are right when a line is "" or a single character I reference line[-1]. Thank you for that, I didn't even notice. Yes, I am using plain text for alice.txt.

JonathanLeffler Thank you. You and BLUEPIXY are right about that. Good catch.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I did strip out the code that was pertinent. I left in the debug/verbose statements in case anyone needed them to debug for themselves and save them from writing more code than they needed to. What would you do with them? Use them to debug and print out to yourself... The entire code is 227 lines with a lot of spaces and comments for readability. Also, did you notice how I posted the affected function to further clarify? I think it was perfectly acceptable how much code I posted and thanks to BLUEPIXY and Jonathan, I have most likely my answer.

Comment: @KevinBoone - for this example of the issue (the project I made is nearly the same except I have a makefile) I used: `gcc version 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6) (GCC)` and compile like so: `gcc -o main main.c`.

Comment: @BrandonAuthier just `int idx = 0;` ?

Comment: @BrandonAuthier umm no, we're not interested in the debugging prints. The presence of scroll bars just makes it harder to see the actual error. And it makes it doubly harder for any reader

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I figured that people would need to actually copy paste the code and run valgrind and mess with the code to get some results. However, since both you and Johnathan complained about its verbosity I can accept that it was not minimal enough. I saw it from my perspective and how I would answer this question if I were to come across it. I see that this is not the best approach and I can use both of your feedback for future posts.

Comment: `A djb2 hash function sourced online.` No, it is *almost* K&R hash, (K&R used xor, IIRC)

Comment: @wildplasser - feel free to click the [link](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)

Comment: https://azrael.digipen.edu/~mmead/www/Courses/CS280/HashFunctions-1.html You are correct. K&R used multiplier=31.

Answer (score 1):

In the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788729/a-memory-issue-in-simple-c-program-concerning-char-pointers#comment78569318_45788729), [Brandon Authier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6646629/brandon-authier) claims that the posted code is close to an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — it has only 227 lines.

I'll contend that the file with 227 lines is over twice as big as necessary; it is not an MCVE.

The code below was saved in a file `so-4578-8729-mcve.c`.  It has 96 lines, and compiles cleanly on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 using GCC 7.2.0 and Valgrind 3.13.0.SVN when compiled using the command:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes so-4578-8729-mcve.c -o so-4578-8729-mcve
$
```

And it runs cleanly under Valgrind on 'Alice in Wonderland':

```
$ valgrind --suppressions=etc/suppressions-macos-10.12.5 -- \
>          so-4578-8729-mcve src/data-files/alice-in-wonderland-pg19033.txt 
==12363== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12363== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12363== Using Valgrind-3.13.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12363== Command: so-4578-8729-mcve src/data-files/alice-in-wonderland-pg19033.txt
==12363== 
==12363== 
==12363== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12363==     in use at exit: 18,188 bytes in 161 blocks
==12363==   total heap usage: 180 allocs, 19 frees, 28,482 bytes allocated
==12363== 
==12363== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12363==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12363==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12363==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12363==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12363==         suppressed: 18,188 bytes in 161 blocks
==12363== 
==12363== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12363== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
$
```

The fixed up code includes the bug fix identified by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788729/a-memory-issue-in-simple-c-program-concerning-char-pointers#comment78535484_45788729).  It is also cleaner with respect to `unsigned char` vs (plain) `char`.  It doesn't have the debug code, or the comments.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool getWord(char *line, int *idx, char *word)
{
    int wordIdx = 0;

    for ( ; line[*idx] != '\0'; *idx = (*idx + 1))
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)line[*idx]) || (line[*idx] == '-'))
        {
            word[wordIdx++] = tolower((unsigned char)line[*idx]);
        }
        else if (isspace((unsigned char)line[*idx]))
        {
            *idx += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

static void processFile(FILE *textFp)
{
    char line[1024] = "";
    char *word = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 50);
    int *lineIdx = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int lineCount = 1;

    *lineIdx = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), textFp) != NULL)
    {
        int charcount = 0;
        int wordCount = 1;

        for (int m = 0; line[m] != '\0'; m++)
        {
            if ((line[m] == ' ') && (m == 0 || line[m - 1] != ' '))
            {
                wordCount++;
            }
            if (line[m] != '\n' && line[m] != '\r')
            {
                charcount++;
            }
            else
            {
                line[m] = '\0';
            }
        }

        while (*lineIdx < (charcount - 1))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                word[i] = '\0';
            }
            getWord(line, lineIdx, word);
        }

        *lineIdx = 0;
        lineCount++;
    }

    free(lineIdx);
    free(word);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s afile.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    processFile(fp);

    if (fclose(fp) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close file '%s'.\n", argv[1]);

    return(0);
}
```

This is close to minimal; it could still be reduced further.  The `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes` options require the functions to be declared `static` — or declared before they are defined.  Since they don't need to be visible outside this source file, they are made `static`.  One advantage of that is that the compiler could tell me that the result of `hash()` was not used, so that the call could be removed, and when that was removed, the `hash()` function was unused, so it could be removed.  Not everyone uses such stringent compilation options, but I prefer the assurances that they give me.

Answer (score -1):

## Feedback

I'd like to begin by thanking everyone for their feedback since most was very helpful.

It seems my presupposition that the community would most likely copy/paste my code into an editor and then compile and run was faulty. This presupposition led me to believe that my posted code was fine in its current amount, but both Jonathan and Antti conveyed that their preference and the MVCE's was less code. I will make sure to post more minimally in the future since that is what the guideline and community prefers.

As for my question and answer this ended up requiring me to go back through and dig into the proper ways to create a char pointer variable. From all the feedback and looking through different examples I have come up with a solution.

Last, thanks to both BluePixy and Jonathan a possible out of bound area index for my line variable was pointed out and I was able to fix that. Unfortunately that wasn't the issue, but was a great catch that I overlooked.

### Proposed Answer

I appreciate the cleaned up code Jonathan, but the code you provided still seg faults the exact same way and has an invalid read and write of 1. I copy/pasted it exactly as it was written and compiled it with the exact same command, but it has the same issue as my original program. I am pretty sure it is because of this line:

```
char *word = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 50);
```

Also, the change of "unsigned char" to "char" is fine here, but in my original program I have a hashing function with an unsigned char and to keep the signatures congruent is why it was an unsigned char. Then you have to cast to an unsigned char later in getWord(). However, that is unimportant to this issue and is fine here since you could just use char pointers all around.

I haven't been able to ascertain why this runs on your Mac and fails on my Linux distro. The short answer to what solved my issue was declaring my "word" variable to:

```
unsigned char word[50] = "";
```

At some point, the word is zero bytes after a 50 block was alloc'd. This was my original point of confusion and I can not see why this happens or why using the above variable assignment fixes that. Clearly, it is because I am not great with memory management and am failing to do something correctly. If you know why, I would appreciate an explanation of what went wrong.

### Answer

It seems to be a small change from:

```
unsigned char *word = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 50);
```

to:

```
unsigned char word[50];
memset(word, '\0', (50 * sizeof(unsigned char)));
```

Is the first one an improper way of creating an unsigned char pointer that will hold 50 characters? I am thinking so since the second works and fixes the issue. I am not understanding something about the first one and that's the issue.

The fixed code is as follows:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int countCharsAndStripNewline(char* line) {
    int charCount = 0;
    while ((line[charCount] != '\n' && line[charCount] != '\r'))
        charCount++;
    line[charCount] = '\0';
    return charCount;
}

static bool getWord(char *line, int *idx, unsigned char *word) {
    int wordIdx = 0;
    for ( ; (line[*idx] != '\0' && wordIdx < 50); *idx = (*idx + 1)) {
        if (wordIdx == 49) {
            word[wordIdx] = '\0';
            *idx += 1;
            return true;
        }
        if (isalpha(line[*idx]) || (line[*idx] == '-'))
            word[wordIdx++] = tolower(line[*idx]);
        else if (isspace(line[*idx])) {
            *idx += 1;
             return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static void processFile(FILE* textFp) {
    char line[1024] = "";
    unsigned char word[50] = "";
    int* lineIdx = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *lineIdx = 0;
    memset(word, '\0', (50 * sizeof(unsigned char)));

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), textFp) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp("",   line) == 0) { continue; }
        if (strcmp(" ",  line) == 0) { continue; }
        if (strcmp("\0", line) == 0) { continue; }
        if (strcmp("\n", line) == 0) { continue; }
        if (strcmp("\r", line) == 0) { continue; }

        int charcount = countCharsAndStripNewline(line);

        while (*lineIdx < (charcount - 1)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                word[i] = '\0';

            getWord(line, lineIdx, word);
        } // End while for word

        *lineIdx = 0;
    } // End while for line

    free(lineIdx);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s afile.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

    if (fp == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    processFile(fp);

    if (fclose(fp) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close file '%s'.\n", argv[1]);

    return(0);
}
```

A few things to note: I added a char counting function for readability and to separate that functionality out. I added the keyword static (as Jonathan pointed out) to each function so that it could keep the strict compilation flags that he used and would help you get rid of unused functions like he pointed out with the hash() function. This is a helpful compilation feature and even though my actual program uses the hash function and is integral in this example it is not and could be removed. I minimized the code, formatted it to use less lines, and stripped out everything suggested by the community so hopefully this is better for people read. Last is I added some quick line checking to skip things that are not important.

Another interesting thing that comes up that is no longer seen now since the hash() function is removed is the "conditional jump" that was on this specific line:

```
while (c = *str++)
```

It would have been great to get some feedback on that, but since Jonathan stripped it out and didn't run into it in his Valgrind check I will have to save that question for another day.

Comment: Moving allocation from malloc to a local variable and having things magically work almost always points to an array over/under flow issue or an initialization issue.  I would consider adding ASSERT conditions on all accesses to your word array to verify that none of your indexes go out of bounds.  Call me skeptical, but I don't think your problem is actually fixed all the way.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan do you mind looking at the two different ways and actually explaining if there is something apparently wrong with malloc declaration or should it in fact allocate a char pointer 50 unsigned chars wide? If you were to read all the code and suggest a proper code fix that would be really helpful since your vague "add assert conditions" doesn't really help me understand much or help me fix the issue.

Comment: Note that I didn't know anything about your answer; people get told about comments made to their answer, or about edits to it, but not about other people's answers.  So, it was only because I was checking whether to remove the code I created that I saw any of this.

Comment: The longest 'word' in the text of Alice that I downloaded is http://www.gutenberg.org/1/9/0/3/19033/ at 40 characters.  Therefore, there was no reason to overrun the 50-character limit.  Maybe you should find your data file and run: `awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf "%d: %s\n", length($i), $i }' alice-in-wonderland-pg19033.txt | sort -nu | tail -20` and look at the twenty longest words — substitute your file name for mine.  If that spots something longer than 49 characters, that would at least tell us that your data is different from mine, and why there was a problem.

Comment: As Michael Dorgan said, the probable reason for the code not crashing is that you're now overwriting a buffer on the stack, but not doing it so badly that it causes a crash.  It also means that Valgrind is less able to spot the trouble.  On the other hand, you have the much bigger array `line` allocated on the stack, so there really isn't an obvious reason to have `word` dynamically allocated.